# How do I test multiple callback in mocha with sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a function with async code and multiple callbacks

```
var f = (cb1, cb2) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { /* ... */ });
};
```

In my test I created tu spy with sinon

```
var cb1Spy = sinon.spy();
var cb2Spy = sinon.spy();
```

To test that they are both called I have a test

```
it('test', (done) => {
  var cbCount = 2;
  var checkIfDone = () => {
    if(--cbCount === 0){
      done()
    }
  };
  f(
    () => { cb1Spy; checkIfDone(); },
    () => { cb2Spy; checkIfDone(); }
  );
});
```

It works but it doesn't feels right.
There are best practices about this kind of test?

Comment: My answer doesn't change much in the presence of this. You still want to use assertions to cause test failures, rather than deliberately failing to invoke the `done` callback in mocha.

Comment: It would help, also, if you specifically described what you're trying to test here. What do these two callbacks represent? What is their relationship with the promise you've returned?

Answer (score 1):

The `done` callback in Mocha is specifically for testing asynchronous code, and is not intended as a means to control success or failure directly.

Your primary means of causing test failure should be thrown Error objects, ideally with messages indicating the reason for the failure. **Assertions** are statements which will throw such errors if some specific condition has not been met. There are many libraries out there for this, of which [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai) is the most popular as far as I know.

Sinon itself [comes with some assertions](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.5/assertions/) to use with its test doubles. For example, if you want to assert that `cb1Spy` was called once, you'd write this:

```
sinon.assert.calledOnce(cb1Spy);
```

If you do end up using chai, there is a nice plugin called [sinon-chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-chai) which you can use to make sinon assertions look more similar to chai's assertions, giving your tests a more consistent syntax. If you use it, you can write your test like this:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const { expect } = chai;
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe('whatever', function() {
    it('test', function() {
        let cb1Spy = sinon.spy();
        let cb2Spy = sinon.spy();

        f(cb1Spy, cb2spy);

        expect(cb1Spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        expect(cb2Spy).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that "f" contains async code. I'm going to edit my question right now.